# How to filter some results in JSON while parsing it

Tags: json, .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm parsing the JSON from [this page](https://api-cloud.bitmart.com/account/v1/currencies) with the following .net framework code:

```
Dim jsonString As String
       Using http As HttpClient = New HttpClient
           Dim url As String = "https://api-cloud.bitmart.com/account/v1/currencies"

           Dim streamData As Stream = Await http.GetStreamAsync(url)

           Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(streamData)
               jsonString = sr.ReadToEnd
           End Using
           streamData.Close()
       End Using

       Dim jsonResponse As JObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString)
       Dim jsonData As JObject = CType(jsonResponse("data"), JObject)
       Dim jsonCurrencies As JArray = CType(jsonData("currencies"), JArray)

       Dim c As String = String.Empty
       Dim n As String = String.Empty
       For Each jsonCurrency As JObject In jsonCurrencies
           c += jsonCurrency("currency").ToString + " - " & jsonCurrency("network").ToString + vbLf

       Next
       RichTextBox1.Text += c
```

it is working perfectly, but I thought all the results were on "true, true"
but the now I sow there are also results like

> "withdraw_enabled":false,"deposit_enabled":false}
> which I really don't need to be parsed.

the results I'm interested on are firstly

> "withdraw_enabled":true,"deposit_enabled":true}

and in cases like the following, I would like to parse them but I want to know which between withdraw and deposit is on true and/or false

> "withdraw_enabled":false,"deposit_enabled":true}

As a summary:

if JSON is

```
[{"currency":"DFC","name":"DefiConnect","network":"BEP20","withdraw_enabled":true,"deposit_enabled":true},
```

the output is

> DFC - BEP20 ( my code is already working for this case)

if JSON is

```
{"currency":"HOG","name":"HOG Finance","network":"BEP20(BSC)","withdraw_enabled":true,"deposit_enabled":false},
```

the output should be

> HOG - BEP20(BSC) [withdraw: Yes - deposit: NO]

and if JSON is

```
{"currency":"SGE","name":"Society of Galactic Exploration","network":"ERC20","withdraw_enabled":false,"deposit_enabled":false}
```

I dont need to parse it.

Do you think It could be possible?
Hope I've been clear.
Thanks

Comment: If you parse the json into an object that includes the json properties you can simply do any additional processing, after parsing, by referencing those properties.

Comment: am I already parsing the json into an object, isnt it? if not, would you be able to make me an example? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the generic JObject, you can deserialize into an actual class.

```vb
    Public Class RootObject
        Public Property Message As String
        Public Property Code As Integer
        Public Property Trace As String
        Public Property Data As Data
    End Class
    
    Public Class Data
        Public Property Currencies As Currency()
    End Class

    Public Class Currency
        Public Property Currency As String
        Public Property Name As String
        Public Property Network As String
        Public Property Withdraw_enabled As Boolean
        Public Property Deposit_enabled As Boolean
    End Class
```

Then in your processing, just check if either property is true.

```vb
    Dim root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(jsonString)
    Dim builder As New StringBuilder()

    For Each currency As Currency In root.Data.Currencies
        'Only consider the currency if at least one enabled is true
        If currency.Withdraw_enabled OrElse currency.Deposit_enabled Then
            builder.Append(currency.Currency)
            builder.Append(" - ")
            builder.AppendLine(currency.Network)
        End If
    Next

    RichTextBox1.Append(builder.ToString())
```

Comment: hei  anubis thanks for your reply, but I probably misunderstanding your solution.
The code I'm using is this one [link](https://pastebin.com/EPLQrG6w) but I'm getting the error ": 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[WindowsApp2.Form1+Currency]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly." on the line "Dim currencyList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Currency))(json)". What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: I edited to use your full data model.

Comment: yeah, I created other 2 classes and now it is also showing withdraw/deposit yes or no. Thanks, nice solution!